# Change HTML structure of form?

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I want to alter the HTML structure for a particular form in my site.  Specifically, I want to add some wrapper DIVs around a few sets of form elements.  What's the "Drupal 7" way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement [hook_element_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/7) to change the theme wrappers used by the form fields.

If you look at the code of [system_element_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_element_info/7), you will notice the form fields are defined as in the following code.

```
  $types['textfield'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE, 
    '#size' => 60, 
    '#maxlength' => 128, 
    '#autocomplete_path' => FALSE, 
    '#process' => array('ajax_process_form'), 
    '#theme' => 'textfield', 
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('form_element'),
  );
  $types['machine_name'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE, 
    '#default_value' => NULL, 
    '#required' => TRUE, 
    '#maxlength' => 64, 
    '#size' => 60, 
    '#autocomplete_path' => FALSE, 
    '#process' => array('form_process_machine_name', 'ajax_process_form'), 
    '#element_validate' => array('form_validate_machine_name'), 
    '#theme' => 'textfield', 
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('form_element'),
  );
  $types['password'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE, 
    '#size' => 60, 
    '#maxlength' => 128, 
    '#process' => array('ajax_process_form'), 
    '#theme' => 'password', 
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('form_element'),
  );
```

You can add a new form wrapper, or change the existing one. Suppose, for example, that you want to add a theme wrapper for the textfield form field; you could use code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  if (isset($type['textfield'])) {
    $type['textfield']['#theme_wrappers'] = array_unshift($type['textfield']['#theme_wrappers'], 'mymodule_textfield_wrapper');
  }
}
```

Your module then should implement the `theme_mymodule_textfield_wrapper()` theme function, and  [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) to declare it.
You can use the code of [theme_form_element()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) as guideline to write your code. The form element is contained in `$variables['element']`.

Alternatively, if the form fields you want to wrap with additional HTML use all the same theme wrapper, you can override that theme function using [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7). Be careful, as in this case you are also altering every form field using that theme wrapper, including future form fields for which your wrapper could cause issues.

Comment: I guess the logical follow up question to this is: how do you add your own custom theme wrapper?